# OpenFeint disk space footprint

Tags: size, disk, space, openfeint, footprint

How much size does OpenFeint add to your binary?

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if it satisfies you?

Answer (score 0):

My android app. was 122 KB. After OpenFeint integration it is 367KB now.
OpenFeint overhead is nearly 250KB.